# .success not returning xml data correctly in ajax call

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, xsd, each

I am trying to target elements down three levels in an xml documet. It strangely goes through the each function 13 times but doesn't return anything each time.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<webpages xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <course id="1">
        <photos>
            <photo>image1.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image2.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image3.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image4.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image5.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image6.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image7.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image8.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image9.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image10.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image11.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image12.jpg</photo>
            <photo>image13.jpg</photo>
        </photos>
    </course>

</webpages>
```

the success on the ajax call:

```
success: function(entry) {
        $self.html("");        // removes the "loading..." notification from container
        $self.append('<h1>Multimedia Gallery</h1>');
        // gets and parse each child element in <webpages>
        $self.append('<div class="galleryTitle"><h4>Photos</h4></div>');
        $(entry).find('photos').children().each(function() {
          // gets the "id", "title", and "url" of current child element
            var elm = $(this);
            var photo = elm.find('photo').text();
            alert(photo);


            // display data
            $self.append('<div class="photos"><img src="img/photos/'+photo+'" alt="" /></div>');

        });
```

if using done: is a successful methos then I will restructure but i do not think that is the problem here. Any thoughts?? If you need more info please tell me what other code you need, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the each loop `this` refers to photo nodes so `elm.find('photo').text();` should be `elm.text();`

Comment: Wow I feel stupid but in my defense I have been at it for three days straight LOL Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `elm` is `$('photos').children()`, then what does `elm.find('photo')` return?
I'm guessing nothing as you already have the photo elements in `elm`, and don't have to use `find()` at all?

```
$(entry).find('photos').children().each(function() {
      var div = $('<div />', {'class':'photos'}),
          img = $('<img />', {src: 'img/photos/'+$(this).text(), alt: ''});

      $self.append( div.append(img) );
});
```